# Regex not ignoring match

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:
`^(?P<X1>.*?(?!\.00))(?:\s(?P<X2>[0-9\.]*))$`

And it should not match this:

`Lore Ipsum. Lore 3.00 3.00`

`Lore Ipsum. Lore 3.00 Lore Ipsum 3.00`

It still needs to capture this:

`Lore Ipsum. Lore 3.00`

`Lore Ipsum. Lore 1 3.00`

I am doing the negative lookahead, but for some reason the first 3.00 is still being captured, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?!.*\.00.*\s\S+$)\s?(?P<X1>.*?)(?:\s(?P<X2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?$
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/Utq9Ae/5).

The point here is to use a lookahead at the start of string and fail the match if there is `.00` before the final word.

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.00.*\s\S+$)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is any text, `.00`, any text, whitespace, one or more non-whitespace chars and end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(?P<X1>.*?)` - Group "X1": any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?:\s(?P<X2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace and then an "X2" group capturing one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I changed the lookahead to a lookbehind.... it also worked, but I dont quite get why, since this comes after not before

Comment: @Walucas Lookbehinds checks for its pattern *immediately **to the left*** of the current location, and lookaheads check for their pattern matches immediately ***on the right***.

Comment: but then, if I have 3.00 on the middle of the string, it will just accepts it on X1, let me update the question with a few more samples, sorry for not adding it before, I am just getting those examples now